# Wrong encoding in url when set extra headers

Tags: typescript, puppeteer, urlencode

Hello Team I have the following code into puppeteer

```
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 800 });
    await page.setRequestInterception(true);
    page.on('request', preventApplicationRedirect(options.callbackUrl));
    await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
        Origin: 'h******',
        'id': 'value',
        'user-agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    });
```

and when I do     `content = await page.content();`
the content is something like this

```
<html><head><meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark"></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{"login_url":"https://URL\u0026redirect_uri=value"}
</pre></body></html>
```

How could I do to decode `\u0026` to `&` in the headers
I tried doing

```
    const encoded = encodeURI(uri);
    const decoded = decodeURI(encoded);
```

but instead of `&` I obtained `&amp;`

Comment: `decodeURI("https://URL\u0026redirect_uri=value")` gives me `'https://URL&redirect_uri=value'` in Node 18.16.1. Skip using `encodeURI()`. If that doesn't work, the string may be something other than you think it is. How are you extracting that JSON from the `<pre>`? Please provide a complete, runnable [mcve]. Providing context like the site and what you're trying to accomplish would make it easier to help, because there may be a simpler solution than you presuppose. Thanks.